# Render nothing after upload rails without reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, upload, render

I am trying to make an app that user can send email to admin with image attachment which user can upload. The problem is, the user has to upload the image first to send the email. That went well. This is my controller:

```
file = File.join("public", "upload", params[:file_upload][:attachment].original_filename)
    File.open(file, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:file_upload][:feedback_attachment].read) }
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
    end
```

But I have to reload the page after the upload which I don't want to do. Is there any way to do it? I tried render :nothing, but it returns an empty page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should make ajax file upload and then handle the success,

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Use this plugin to do a file upload And then handle the success.

Comment: @takodil, U have to include the latest jquery in the asset pipeline. In application.js and also include this plugin, or u can directly include javascripts in the layout file and use it directly, Like 2nd snippet on the quickstart guide given on that link.